# Django models referencing each other

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

I have two models and I want to put an if condition in my template to get the desired output.
I have the first model

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    books = models.ForeignKey('Books')
```

And the second one

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And a view

```
def View(request):
    subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    return render('my_html.html",{'subjects':subjects})
```

In my model, I have wanted to do this.

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
    {% if subject.books.count > 0 %}
        {{ subject.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I thought the only way is to have the models referencing each other for my plan to work but I also think that looping will require more resources. Is there a better way of doing this either thro' the view or just in the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to `ForeignKey` from `Book` to `Subject`, so:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # no books

class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then you can filter the subjects such that it only retrieves `Subject`s with at least one book:

```
def view(request):
    subjects = Subject.objects.filter(books__isnull=False).distinct()
    return render(request, 'my_html.html', {'subjects': subjects})
```

this will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the table of the `Book` model, and check if there is at least one book. You thus do not need to filter in the template (which is not a good idea anyway).

Comment: @Wllem Van Onsem. Can I do a filter on the Books model before passing it here? Something like books= Books.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Comment: @fakeMake: yes, if the `Books` has a `user` field, you can filter. If you want to only retrieve `Subject`s for which there is a `Books` with that user, you filter with `Subject.objects.filter(books__user=request.user).distinct()`.